# Create list from one long string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

So bassicly I have this list that contains one long string of data (the lenght of the string can vary):

```
    ['{0 1} {1 5} {1 8} {1 10} {2 5} {2 7} {2 4} {3 4} {4 9} {5 6}']
```

and I need this:

```
  [[0,1],[1,5],[1,8],[1,10],[2,5],[2,7],[2,4],[3,4],[4,9],[5,6]]
```

But I have absolutely no idea how to do this... any ideas?

Comment: You need to think about a pseudo algorithm, then find the associated python functions. For instance, your first step here would be to cut the string using a well-known marker (space character here), then work on individual substrings. A pointer to start: `s.split()` will cut your string s into a list of substrings delimited by a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` with `str.replace` for this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

x = ['{0 1} {1 5} {1 8} {1 10} {2 5} {2 7} {2 4} {3 4} {4 9} {5 6}']

res = list(map(list, literal_eval('[' + x[0].replace(' ', ',') + ']')))

print(res)

# [[0, 1], [1, 5], [8, 1], [1, 10], [2, 5], [2, 7], [2, 4], [3, 4], [9, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Remove the outermost braces, then split on `"} {"`, and split again on space:

```
text = '{0 1} {1 5} {1 8} {1 10} {2 5} {2 7} {2 4} {3 4} {4 9} {5 6}'

result = [[int(num) for num in group.split()] for group in text[1:-1].split('} {')]
# [[0, 1], [1, 5], [1, 8], [1, 10], [2, 5], [2, 7], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 9], [5, 6]]
```

**Option 2:** Use regex:

```
import re

result = [[int(num) for num in match.groups()] for match in re.finditer(r'(\d+) (\d+)', text)]
# [[0, 1], [1, 5], [1, 8], [1, 10], [2, 5], [2, 7], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 9], [5, 6]]
```